# Prettiest way to declare a C array either fixed size or variable size?

Tags: c, arrays, embedded

I am writing a small C code for an algorithm. The main target are embedded microcontrollers, however, for testing purposes, a Matlab/Python interface is required.

I am following an embedded programming standard (MISRA-C 2004), which requires the use of C90, and discourage the use of `malloc` and friends. Therefore, all the arrays in the code have their memory allocated at compile time. If you change the size of the input arrays, you need to recompile the code, which is alright in the microcontroller scenario.
However, when prototyping with Matlab/Python, the size of the input arrays change rather often, and recompiling every time does not seem like an option. In this case, the use of C99 is acceptable, and the size of the arrays should be determined in runtime.

The question is: what options do I have in C to make these two scenarios coexist in the same code, while keeping the code clean?

I must emphasize that my main concern is how to make the code easy to maintain. I have considered using *#ifdef* to either take the statically allocated array or the dynamically alocated array. But there are too many arrays, I think *#ifdef* makes the code look ugly.

Comment: How is the runtime value for the size determined?  Presumably it must be calculated or input from somewhere; you can't avoid a conditional (whether `#if` or `if`) to skip that calculation/IO in the statically-sized case.

Comment: In your python code you could generate the relevant bits of .c and .h code.  That would make it easy to maintain because it's auto-generated

Comment: @TJD the auto-generated approach is also a nice idea. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've thought of a way that you can get away with only one `#ifdef`.  I would personally just bite the bullet and recompile my code when I need to.  The idea of using a different dialect of C for production and test makes me a bit nervous.

Anyway, here's what you can do.

```
#ifdef EMBEDDED
#define ARRAY_SIZE(V,S) (S)
#else
#define ARRAY_SIZE(V,S) (V)
#endif

int myFunc(int n)
{
    int myArray[ARRAY_SIZE(n, 6)];
    // work with myArray
}
```

The `ARRAY_SIZE` macro chooses the variable `V`, if not in the embedded environment; or the fixed size `S`, if in the embedded environment.

Comment: Brilliant! I personally would recompile everytime, but the code is intended to be used by others as well. And mixing dialects is definitely ugly (to say the least). But as I said, C99 is _acceptable_, not mandatory.

Comment: ...or just `#ifdef EMBEDDED int myArray[n]; #else int myArray[6]; #endif`

Comment: @Lundin the problem is there is more than one array and the questioner wants to minimise the `#ifdef`s

Answer (score 1):

MISRA-C:2004 forbids C99 and thereby VLAs, so if you are writing strictly-conforming MISRA code you can't use them. It is also very likely that VLAs will be explicitly banned in the upcoming MISRA-C standard.

Is it an option not to use statically allocated arrays of unknown size? That is:

```
uint8_t arr[] = { ... };  
... 
n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(uint8_t);
```

This is most likely the "prettiest" way. Alternatively you can have a debug build in C99 with VLAs, and then change it to statically allocated arrays in the release build.

Comment: VLA seems not like an option, by what you mentioned. It is not clear to me what do you mean with "Is it an option not to use statically allocated arrays of unknown size?".

Comment: @user1069152 Setting the array dimension automatically in runtime depending on the number of elements in the array. `arr[] = ` rather than `arr[10] = `, as in my example.